# How can a webpage be getting updated if there is no incoming network traffic?

Tags: ajax, network-traffic

I have recently started learning about AJAX and how to efficiently update webpages. In doing so, I often look at the network traffic of sites in the development tools of Google Chrome.

I recently came across something I found curious, the site [William Hill](http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb/betlive/all) seems to update live odds on their in play page without any incoming network traffic to do with the odds they are updating. This can be seen by opening up the network traffic analyser in Google Chrome and noting that the odds update without any new network files being received.

How is this being accomplished?

Comment: There will definitely be network traffic - you could see it with a tool like WireShark. Probably, Chrome's developer tools are just not tracking it. The site is probably using something like [Server-Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) or maybe [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: [They are using flash in an iframe.](http://pushsc1.williamhill.com/push_api.html?ver=35c36e89ef751b74c7aa3b07d7e0f6b6) (View Source)  Chrome doesn't show you flash traffic, but Firefox does.

Comment: I can't see the network traffic even when using Firefox and that link is to an empty page. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough.  Check the source of that empty page, that's why I added (View Source) in parenthesis.  Once you see the source, you will see javascript that uses a flash object to connect to a server and get data.  In Firefox, go to your link, hit F12 and go to the network tab. You will see the request made by flash.  I barely use Firefox so it should work with the default configuration.